# Streamed html from SQL doesn't display images in IE9

Tags: image, c#-4.0, internet-explorer-9, httpresponse

I have an html file stored in my SQL database as binary. The html contains image directories, and the images are stored in those directories on the server.

Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE7, and IE8 all display the images and html text, but IE9 just displays the html text and the words 'bitmap' in place of the images.

This code outputs the html:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2000");
Response.Expires = 0;
b = Compression.DeCompressByteArray(b);
Response.OutputStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
Response.End();
```

This is just a snippet showing the main output procedure.

Copying the image directories from the output html and placing it in my address bar opens the images, but IE9 doesn't want to display them inside the html and instead displays the word 'bitmap'

**Furthermore:**

- The html(and images) output from SQL,
  when run as a standalone html works
  on all browsers.
- The images do    display in IE9 when
  embed, if I have    compatibility
  mode on (but that    breaks other
  stuff).

Comment: My question was not about the HTML output from SQL. My question was about the HTML output by C# (view source). I am betting there is a significant difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question:

The html streamed from my SQL Server doesn't define a doctype and is therefore run in Quirks Mode in IE8 down. IE9 forces an iframe without a doctype to use the doctype of it's parent.

The html is from the output of excel which doesn't produce a doctype when published.

Answer (score 1):

How you write the HTML (meaning via C# or whatever, or that it came from SQL Server) is almost certainly irrelevant here. I would suggest viewing the source, confirming that the source HTML (without any interference from ASP.NET, SQL Server, etc.) still exhibits the problem, and post that (and re-tag to reflect that C# and SQL Server have nothing to do with the problem). Also make sure to mention whether it works better when you use compatibility mode.

Comment: I've updated the question. Running the html outside my aspx page works, so it must have something to do with the response in the c#

Comment: What do you mean? So if you view the source of the ASPX page (which doesn't work), save that as an HTML file, and open that as HTML, it works? What are the results when using compatibility mode?

Comment: I've taken both the html directly from sql and the html from view source and saved it as it's own html file. Running it out of the .aspx page works, but not when embed in the .aspx. The html does differ very slightly, but works the same.

The html output is embed in an iframe, I wonder if that's the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to specify the content type for your response. Those headers are missing.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208(v=vs.90).aspx

ie, do:

> Response.ContentType = "text/HTML"

Comment: Yeah, that's the 1st thing I tried. It makes no difference. 
Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";